# Persist an entity with @JoinColumn not pointing to any ID attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity `ConfigurationEntity` that has an attribute `dayOfTheWeek` that can have a value of 1-7. When client fetches GET`.../configuration` they want to have both names and codes (1-7). Respecting decomposition I created a `DictionaryEntity` which maps to table which stores values

```
id   | group        | name    | code
123  | dayOfTheWeek | Monday  | 1
124  | dayOfTheWeek | Tuesday | 2
etc..
```

I have defined the `ConfigurationEntity` as

(I'm omitting some details and annotations that I believe are not important in the problem)

```
class ConfigurationEntity {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(column = "dayOfTheWeek", referenceColum = "code", table = "dictionary")
  @Where("dictionary.group = 'dayOfTheWeek'")
  @JsonIgnore
  private DictionaryEntity dayOfTheWeekDictionary;

  @JsonProperty
  public Number getDayOfTheWeek() {
    return this.dayOfTheWeekDictionary.code;
  }

  @JsonProperty
  public String getDayOfTheWeekDescription() {
    return this.dayOfTheWeekDictionary.name;
  }
}
```

And this works resulting in response to GET:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "dayOfTheWeek": 1,
  "dayOfTheWeekDescription": "Monday"
}
```

The problem is when client wants to submit some changes to `ConfigurationEntity` and sends following PATCH request:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "dayOfTheWeek": 2
}
```

Hibernate/JPA (I'm generally confused which one does what exactly) can persist that (with some hacks) but the `repository.save(entity)` returns me a records with `dayOfTheWeekDictionary` equal `null`. Same goes for `repository.getById(id)`. After calling GET again client receives properly mapped/joined record.

The question is: how to persist an entity knowing only the `dictionary.code` so that hibernate can find a corresponding `DictionaryEntity` for that record?

I realize that `DictionaryEntity` actually has a composite key (group, code). I can add this key but still, client only knows one part of the key and the entity knows the second part (@Where clause). I can fetch the `DictionaryEntity` by myself but what if I have a 100 tables with 200 fields joined with `dictionary` table? I want the solution to be abstract/generic.

Answer (score 1):

This is a design issue. Here's what I think is wrong and how I think you should fix that.

First: you don't need any database table to specify that 1 is Monday and 2 is Tuesday. This should simply be hard-coded in your code: that will never, ever change. All you would need is a properly defined enum and a custom JSON serializer that serializes an instance of this enum to an object with the code and the name of the day:

```
"dayOfTheWeek": {
  "code": 1,
  "name": "Monday"
}
```

Now for the API allowing to modify a configuration entity. There is absolutely no reason to let any client submit the name of a day. The goal is to change a configuration entity, this entity has a day of the week that is uniquely and unambiguously identified by a numeric code. So, to change the day of the configuration entity, all you need is a new day code. Sending a new day name is both redundant and confusing (as your question shows). So design your API input as an object requiring a day code, but no day name.

As an example, see the github REST API. If you [get an issue](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#get-a-single-issue) you will get, as part of the issue in the response, an assignee object with plenty of details about the assignee: the login identifying the assignee, but also his/her gravatar, URLs, etc.

But if you submit a new issue, the only information needed is the ID of the assignee of the issue. The gravatar and the URLs of the assignee are useless, and submitting them would be confusing, since the API doesn't want (and may not) change the details of the assignee. So, [what does the API take as input](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#edit-an-issue)? An object containing just a string for the assignee, and this string only contains what uniquely identifies the assignee: his/her login.

Replace "issue" by "configuration entity", and "assignee" by "day of week", and you have the same situation as yours.

Comment: Yes, I don't need it for name of weekdays but this was just an example (maybe not very fitting). It's cannot be hardcoded because this will change. The names can change any given moment and there can be new values. Think of the `dictionary` table as storage for options for select lists in the frontend. And I do not understand what you mean in the first paragrahp under the code snippet. That's exactly what I am asking about :)

Comment: M point still stands for your dopdown option. The label of an option is only useful to **display** an option. When the client wants to **choose** one of the options, the only thing it should submit is the ID or code which identifies the option. Not its label, which should not change, and is useless. So, get the code of the submitted  option from the JSON document sent by the client, then get the corresponding DictionaryEntity from the database using JPA (using a query which finds an entity by code and group), then update yoyr entity with the found DictionaryEntity.

Comment: I wouldn't use a single table to store unrelated information, BTW. Just use a separate table, mapped to a separate entity, allowing to have additional properties in the future if necessary, for each of your entities. day of weeks have no reason to be stored in the same table as customer categories or any other thing that can be chosen in a dropdown.

Comment: yes. I want the client to submit only the "code" not the label. The problem is HOW to get the DictionaryEntity by this code in a generic/abstract manner so I don't have to explicitly override every `save` method and fetch the dicitionary. I want Hibernate to do that using Annotations.

Comment: It shouldn't be generic. If the submitted code is supposed to be the code of a day of week, you should get and validate the day of week, and not any other kind of entity. Hibernate allows managing your persistence layer. It's not a tool to handle a RESTful API. Don't mix the two layers.

Comment: So you encourage me to make a solution that violates DRY? Thanks, but I'm looking for other solutions. Persistence is exactly what I want here. Imagine I was referencing a foreign key (not an ordinary column), there wouldn't be any problem and it WOULD be generic.

Comment: Err no, it wouldn't be. If you edited a github issue and submitted a new assignee login (or ID), you would use userRepository.findByLogin (or findById) to get the **user** identified by this login or ID. Same here. And if you edited the issue and submitted a new **project** ID for the issue, you would use projectRepository.findById() to get the project. Different entities, having different properties, stored in different tables, handled by different repositories.